# What is the value of x in $2 = x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \dots}} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-points

If $x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \cdots}} = 2$, what is the value of $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: "If x is equal to 2, what is the value of x?" $$ $$ It's two, and I'm not going to open the link to check what you really meant. Please edit the question so it makes sense

Comment: Also, this is not an infinite series but rather a nested radical.

Comment: @Adeesh.Jain: There are some problems with the question. As Yuriy.S points out, it is incorrectly stated. Moreover, it is a link to an image which could have easily been typeset with MathJax instead. Lastly, no effort was shown by the poster to solve the problem. I have edited the question to fix the first two issues, but you should keep this in mind for future questions. Otherwise, you will likely continue to receive down/close votes and not have much luck getting help from the users of this website.

Answer (score 3):

The only reasonable interpretation of
$$
x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}
$$
is as the limit of a sequence $(y_{n})_{n}$ satisfying
$$
y_{n+1}=x+\sqrt{y_{n}}.
$$
If this sequence has a nonnegative limit $y$, then taking limits of both sides and using the fact that limits and continuous functions (namely, $\sqrt{\cdot}$) commute, we get $y=x+\sqrt{y}$.
Equivalently,
$$
y-\sqrt{y}-x=0.
$$
Now, let $w=\sqrt{y}$ so that
$$
w^{2}-w-x=0.
$$
This is a quadratic equation in $w$ and we can solve it to get
$$
w=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}.
$$
In your case, $w=\sqrt{2}$.
However, to keep matters general, let's proceed *without* this assumption.
Moving some terms around,
$$
2w-1=\pm\sqrt{1+4x}.
$$
Squaring both sides,
$$
x=\frac{\left(2w-1\right)^{2}-1}{4}.
$$

Returning to the case of interest, we can plug in $w=\sqrt{2}$ to the above to get $$\boxed{x=2-\sqrt{2} \approx 0.58579.}$$
We can verify that this is indeed the correct answer by looking at the first "few" iterations of the sequence with $y_0 = x$, which can be seen converging to $2$:

```
y_0 = 0.585786437627
y_1 = 1.35115330236
y_2 = 1.74817763785
y_3 = 1.9079731256
y_4 = 1.96708044167
y_5 = 1.98831288717
y_6 = 1.99586192751
y_7 = 1.99853621289
y_8 = 1.99948237838
y_9 = 1.99981698128
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [wiki page for nested radicals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) you will find the formula (for $n>0$)
$$
\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\ldots}}}
= \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4n}}{2}
$$
This implies
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}
= 2 - x,
$$
showing $x = 2 - \sqrt{2}$.

This formula can be shown like this: 
Let $\phi := \sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\ldots}}}$. Then $\phi^2 = n + \phi$. This is a quadratic in $\phi$ which one can easily solve with the quadratic formula. You have to choose the positive solution since roots of positive numbers are positive.